# Failure while accessing Bcd using wmic

Tags: wmic, bcdstore

I am getting an error when I try to access the EnumerateObjects method of the BcdStore class using wmic.

I initially ran the GetSystemDisk method to see that I can access the BcdStore (see below). This worked fine.

> __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__ *cmd window output begins* __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___
>
> C:>wmic /namespace:\root\wmi class BcdStore call GetSystemDisk
>
> Executing (BcdStore)->GetSystemDisk()
>
> Method execution successful.
>
> Out Parameters:
>
> instance of __PARAMETERS
>
> {
>
> ```
>     Disk = "\\Device\\Harddisk0\\DR0";
>
>     ReturnValue = TRUE;
> ```
>
> };
>
> __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__ *cmd window output ends* __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___

Then I ran the EnumerateObjects method, but got a failure, please see below.  The different versions are just different variations of how to pass the arguments to the method, But this didn't work.

> __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__ *cmd window output begins* __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___
>
> C:>wmic /namespace:\root\wmi class BcdStore call EnumerateObjects 10200003
>
> Executing (BcdStore)->EnumerateObjects()
>
> ERROR:
>
> Description = Invalid method Parameter(s)
>
> C:>wmic /namespace:\root\wmi class BcdStore call EnumerateObjects Type=10200003
>
> Executing (BcdStore)->EnumerateObjects()
>
> ERROR:
>
> Description = Invalid method Parameter(s)
>
> C:>wmic /namespace:\root\wmi class BcdStore call EnumerateObjects Type="H10200003"
>
> ERROR:
>
> Description = Type mismatch.
>
> C:>wmic /namespace:\root\wmi class BcdStore call EnumerateObjects 0x10200003
>
> ERROR:
>
> Description = Type mismatch.
>
> __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__ *cmd window output ends* __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer because I'am not sure to really understand what you want to do, but it can be an explanation of why what you do does not work.

The following works because `GetSystemDisk` is a static method of the class `BcdStore` :

```
wmic /namespace:\root\wmi class BcdStore call GetSystemDisk
```

As you can see in the method qualifier of *WMI Cim studio* :

[image]

**But** `EnumerateObjects` is an instance method of the class `BcdStore`, so you can't call it from the class itself, you must call it from an instance. *WMI Object Browser* show no instance on my W2K8R2 for `BcdStore` class.

[image]